# How do I tunnel the NodeJS debugger through to a Vagrant box?

Tags: node.js, ssh, vagrant, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up the WebStorm NodeJS debugger to connect to a NodeJS project hosted on a Vagrant box.  I'm coming up with some difficulties.

If I tunnel into the server the traditional way (ie, via Terminal), it all works fine and I'm able to cURL to it, debug it via WebStorm etc.

```
    ssh -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858  -N vagrant@10.20.30.40
```

Once I'd gotten that working, I put the following into my Vagrantfile:

```
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5858, host: 5858
```

Unlike before, this still works on the Vagrant box but not on my local machine.  When I cURL to it, I get the following error:

```
    curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Is this even possible to configure through the Vagrantfile?

I want to do it through this so my team can connect their debuggers with zero configuration.

Thanks

Comment: I´m having the same issue, did you solved it?

Comment: No.  I sort of think it's impossible with the current Vagrant setting.  It does port forwarding, but tunnelling is an SSH action which seems outside of the way it works.

Going to start a bounty and see if someone can prove me wrong

Comment: this works for me: http://neilk.net/blog/2013/08/21/how-to-debug-node-dot-js-from-within-vagrant/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a provision shell script (tunnel.sh) which would create a remote port forwarding to your machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

# executed from 'vagrant'
ssh -R 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 me@my-machine
```

Actually you should put this script in the same folder than your Vagrantfile, and edit the Vagrantfile to add this lines:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "tunnel.sh"
end
```

This will make Vagrant execute this script every time you execute the command:

```
vagrant up
```

Or:

```
vagrant provision
```

When trying this, you should delete the port forwarding line in your Vagrantfile.

I didn't try the tunnel, but I actually use provision scripts to configure the vm when it starts, like copying public keys in authorized_keys and similar tasks.

Comment: Where would this get put? And have you actually tried it?

Comment: I added more details about how to use a provision script in the answer.